# Ex 4.17 of Rudin, real function on $(a,b)$ has at most countably many simple discontintuiy.

Tags: real-analysis

I am thinking of a (slightly) simpler proof of Ex 4.17 of Rudin, *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, where we don't have to consider the values of $f(x^+)$ and $f(f^-)$.

[image: Rudin, Principles of Mathematical Analysis, Exercise 4.17, image]

Suppose $f$ has a simple discontinuity at $x$, then $f(x^+)$ and $f(x^-)$ exit. While in Rudin's book, $f(x^-)$ is defined by sequence limit, we can easily rephrase it as follows:

> $f(x^-)=p$ is equivalent to $\forall \epsilon,\exists \delta, \forall
>  t$, if $x-\delta<t<x$, then $|f(t)-f(x)|<\epsilon$.

The proof should be similar to Thm 4.2 in Rudin's book: Suppose otherwise, $\exists\epsilon, \forall\delta,\exists t,$ s.t. 
$x-\delta<t<x$ but $|f(t)-f(x)|\ge\epsilon$. We let $\delta=\frac1n$ and choose $x_n$ as such that $x-\delta<x_n<x$ and $x\in(a,b)$ but $|f(x_n)-f(x)|\ge\epsilon$. This contradicts the sequence definition of $f(x^-)$.

Now, I have the following corollary:

> If $f(x^-)$ exists, then $\exists\delta_1,$ s.t., $f$ is (uniformly) continuous in $(x-\delta_1, x)$.

This is given by the fact that $\exists \delta_1,\forall x_1, x_2\in(x-\delta_1,x)$, we have $|f(x_1)-f(x^-)|<\epsilon/2$ and $|f(x_2)-f(x^-)|<\epsilon/2$, impling that $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|<\epsilon$.

We now choose $q\in\mathbb Q$ and $x-\delta_1<q<x$, s.t., $f$ is continuous on $(q, x)$. Likewise, we can also choose $r\in\mathbb Q$, s.t., $f$ is continuous on $(x,r)$. For any given rational pairs $(q,r)$ chosen as such, there's only one point in $(q,r)$ that has a simple discontinuity. We now have a one-one mapping between a simple discontinuity with a subset of rational pairs. Thus the set of simple discontinuity points is at most countable.

My proof seems to be agnostic to the values of $f(x^-)$ and $f(x^+)$, and thus we don't have to discuss three cases about $f(x^-)$ and $f(x^+)$.

I am wondering whether my proof is correct, and if not whether any of my intermediate results is also wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The existence of the one-sided limit $f(x^-)$ does not imply continuity on any interval $(x-\delta,x)$. Simple example is the salt-and-pepper function $f(p/q) = 1/q$ for rational $p/q$ in reduced form, $f(x)=0$ for $x$ irrational. Here $f(x^-)$ and $f(x^+)$ exist for all $x$, but the function is not continuous on any interval.

Comment: Thank you very much. After a second thought, I believe the first intermediate result is still correct, whereas the second is wrong. This is because $\forall x_1, x_2$ satisfying $|x_1-x_2|<\delta_1$, I also required that $x_1,x_2\in(x-\delta_1,x)$, meaning that the interval itself is changing with $\delta_1$.  Therefore, my proof is completely wrong :-(